# ¿Cómo hacer que los bots se comuniquen en telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram.bot

Intento hacer tres bots que se comuniquen entre ellos en Telegram.
Para ello utilizo phyton-telegram-bot.
La idea es hacer tres intercomunicadores ejecutando tres bots iguales en tres raspberry pi.
Empezando con esta idea me doy cuenta de que está restringido que un bot envíe un mensaje directo a otro.

He creado un grupo donde he metido a tres bots y a mi como administradores. Con este código responden a mis mensajes pero no se leen entre ellos.

¿De qué forma pueden estos bots acceder a los mensajes enviados al grupo por los otros bots?

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, InlineQueryHandler, CallbackContext


# Variables de configuración 

I_AM = open("i_am.txt", 'r').read() # Identifica a este clon


if I_AM == "TeteGram1":
    TOKEN = open("conf/token1.txt", 'r').read()
elif I_AM == "TeteGram2":
    TOKEN = open('conf/token2.txt', 'r').read()
elif I_AM == "TeteGram3":
    TOKEN = open('conf/token3.txt', 'r').read()

    # id en context.bot.id
CHANEL_ID = open('conf/TeteGramSaloon_id.txt', 'r').read()

TETES = {
    "TeteGram1_id": open('conf/TeteGram1_id.txt', 'r').read(),
    "TeteGram2_id": open('conf/TeteGram2_id.txt', 'r').read(),
    "TeteGram3_id": open('conf/TeteGram3_id.txt', 'r').read()
}


# Comandos ###########################

def start(update, context):
    '''Comando /start'''

    update.message.reply_text('Hola, Estoy a tope!')


# Funciones ###########################

def sendText(text):
    '''Envia texto al canal'''
    
    bot.send_message(chat_id=CHANEL_ID, text=text)


def ok(update, context):
    '''Responde ok al texto recibido'''

    update.message.reply_text('ok')


def playAudio(update, context):
    '''Reproduce el audio recibido por DM'''

    pass


def sendAudio(audio, users):
    '''Envía el audio a los usuarios'''
    pass



# MAIN #########################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Conexión e inicio de sesión
    updater = Updater(token = TOKEN, use_context= True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    bot = dp.bot
    # Handlers (El orden es relevante)
    handlers_list = [
        # Comando /start
        CommandHandler('start', start),
        MessageHandler(Filters.audio, playAudio),
        MessageHandler(Filters.text, ok),
        
    ]

    for handler in handlers_list:
        dp.add_handler(handler)




    # Bucle de escucha del bot
    updater.start_polling()
    print('Bot is polling')
    
    
    # Enviar mensaje a bot
    sendText(I_AM + " activo")
    updater.idle()
```

Comment: No veo por qué habría de existir esa restricción en un canal telegram. En principio cualquier cosa que se diga en el canal llega a todos los bots conectados al mismo. No creo que se filtre el contenido si proviene de un bot, pero es cuestión de probarlo. Creo que sería la vía a intentar

Comment: Me pongo a ello a ver...

Comment: Cree un grupo con los bots dentro... responden a mis mensajes pero no se responden entre ellos. Parece que los handlers solo gestionan los mensajes enviados por usuarios.

Comment: Sí, parece que no es posible :-( https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get